# Can i ask how do you make a Custom google map that is only in a specific area and how do i create Bounderies of that area

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

[im trying to make something like this and im struggling can anyone help me or give me an idea how to start im also currently new to android development and this is for our capstone project any help is appreciated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcSM6.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

If you're intend to use it in [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview), you can use [Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines).

If it's for [Mobile SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation#:%7E:text=Maps-,Maps%20SDKs,-Bring%20the%20real), you can check out [Add polygons to represent areas on the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial#add_polygons_to_represent_areas_on_the_map).

However, please do note that the two links above need a number of vertices that are **manually** added through LatLngs. You will need to know the location of  every vertex to add it in LatLngs.

If you want to automatically display polygons on a specified geographic boundary, please do note that this feature is currently not available. However, we have an existing Feature Request for “Automatic polygon generation to specified geographic boundary (e.g. state, country)”. You can view and star the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/35816953